# soap error when connecting to MS Exchange

Tags: java, exception, soap, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to connect to a MS Exchange server via soap but im getting the error below. This works from another computer with more or less the exakt same environment (minor version differences on eclipse etc) and we im using different AD accounts on the computers. Have anyone seen this before and could give a hint what might be wrong?

Part of the code that is needed for the exchange connection:

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "ExchangeWebService", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages", wsdlLocation = "mysourceadress/exchange.wsdl")
public class ExchangeWebService
    extends Service
{

    private final static URL EXCHANGEWEBSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(se.ports.webservices.generatedWSDL.ExchangeWebService.class.getName());

    static {
        URL url = null;
        try {   
            URL baseUrl = se.ports.webservices.generatedWSDL.ExchangeWebService.class.getResource(".");
            url = new URL(baseUrl, "../exchange.wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            logger.warning("Failed to create URL for the wsdl Location:'"+ url +"', retrying as a local file");
            logger.warning(e.getMessage());
        }
        EXCHANGEWEBSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }

    public ExchangeWebService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }


javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Can't find input stream in message
           at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:146)
           at $Proxy48.findItem(Unknown Source)
           at se.ports.webservices.io.ItemTypeDAO.getFolderItems(ItemTypeDAO.java:44)
           at se.ports.webservices.access.ExchangeFacade.getAllEmails(ExchangeFacade.java:38)
           at se.ports.webservices.utils.ExchangeFacadeTest.getAllEmails(ExchangeFacadeTest.java:25)
           at se.ports.webservices.ExchangeTests.test_single_exchangefacade_try_exchange_connection(ExchangeTests.java:34)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
           at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
           at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:699)
           at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:891)
           at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1215)
           at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
           at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
           at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:758)
           at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:613)
           at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
           at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
           at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
           at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
           at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
           at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:87)
           at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1170)
           at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1095)
           at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
           at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:109)
           at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:202)
           at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:173)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find input stream in message
           at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:116)
           at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:60)
           at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:255)
           at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:755)
           at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:2330)
           at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:2192)
           at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:2036)
           at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
           at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:696)
           at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
           at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:255)
           at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:516)
           at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:313)
           at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:265)
           at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
           at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:124)
           ... 29 more
```

**UPDATE:**

So after a lot of trial and error testing I'v come to realize that the problem is that one of the computers run with jdk7, this fails, while the others run with jdk6 and that works great (i'v also added jdk7 on the working computers and then they also fail). I tried to solve this by re-running wsimport from jdk7 instead but that still gives the same error for jdk7 and totally breaks for the jdk6 computers. Anyone got a idé how to solve this?

---

So after a lot of trial and error testing I'v come to realize that the problem is that one of the computers run with jdk7, this fails, while the others run with jdk6 and that works great (i'v also added jdk7 on the working computers and then they also fail). I tried to solve this by re-running wsimport from jdk7 instead but that still gives the same error for jdk7 and totally breaks for the jdk6 computers. Anyone got a idé how to solve this?

Comment: check this thread: https://community.jboss.org/thread/160844

Comment: @Waqas I'm using chunking and everything works great with jdk6 but it fails for jdk7 (see update). got any tip? thx for link though

Comment: Not a direct answer, but why use soap directly with EWS when there is already a nice Java API: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi

Comment: @Charlie great advice! I tried it out and it worked without any problems for both jdk6 and jdk7